# ctx.fillstyle can it be changed?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to figure out if you ctx.fillStyle 'red' lets say, can it be updated to green and so on.

```
if(me.healthPoints >= 7){
   ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
   } else if(me.healthPoints >=4 && me.healthPoints <= 6){  
     ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
     } else if(me.healthPoints <= 3){
       ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
       }
```

Right now it's staying as green and not changing to any other color, yet the health points get updated so it seems to be something with the fill style.

Comment: Of course it can. Your problem is in an other castle, and we can't see it, hence we can't help you.

Comment: What is it you need to see? @Kaiido

Comment: Your code? I guess you are drawing something after you changed this `fillStyle` property. If you aren't, then you won't see the update, for sure.

Comment: @Kaiido  This is what sits ontop of that code `ctx.fillRect(x - hpBar/2, y - 25, hpBar,4);`

Comment: You need to set the `fillStyle` **before** calling `fill()` or `fillRect()`, otherwise it will use what was set before. The canvas has no idea of an object, and all drawing operations are like real drawing, with a pen on a sheet of paper. If you hold the yellow pen when you draw, then you'll draw yellow, even though after you pick the green one.

Comment: Can you type this up as an answer, it could help others and I will set it as answered, it's working now. @Kaiido

Comment: Sorry, I am reluctant to answer such basic questions which would have been answered by simple reading of docs / tutos on the subject. Moreover when the actual problem is hidden in a set of comments.

Comment: What might be basic to you might not be to others, my mistake would be made by many others. But it's okay I will write up my mistake and the answer, I'm sure others will benefit from this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they won't, and I'm pretty sure you are not the first one to come into this indeed, and I may also have fallen there once. But the problem is that when we fall in such a problem, we don't know how to search for it, otherwise, you would have found this by yourself. And I sincerily doubt this Q/A will change anything to this.